help me to solve this hypergeometric integral: $ \int_0^x y^{\alpha-1}\,_2F_1 \left(a+b, a; a+1; \frac{a t}{(b-1)y}\right) dy $
I am a PhD scholar. In my research, I have to solve the equation in hypergeometric function:
$$
\int_{0}^{x}y^{\alpha - 1}\,
_{2}\!\operatorname{F}_{1}\left(a + b,a;a + 1; \frac{at}{\left[b - 1\right]y}\right){\rm d}y
$$

I have gone through the books, i.e.,

Table of Integrals, Series, and Products.
Integrals and Series Volume $1$ to $5$: More Special Functions
and $\tt Wolfram.com$.



to find any $\underline{\mbox{suitable formula}}$ that can give me the solution to my objective.

One of the $\underline{\mbox{suitable formula}}$ I have got from all three is as follows:
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{y}x^{\alpha - 1}\left(y - x\right)^{\beta - 1}\,_{2}\!\operatorname{F}_{1} \left(a, b; c; -wx\right)\,{\rm d}x
\\[3mm] = & \
\operatorname{B}\left(\alpha,\beta\right) y^{\alpha + \beta - 1}\,_{3}\!\operatorname{F}_{2} \left(a,b,\alpha;c,\alpha + \beta; -wy\right)
\end{align}
But there is only one problem: in my question, there is
$$
{}_{2}\!\operatorname{F}_{1}\left(a + b,a;a + 1; \frac{at}{\left[b - 1\right]y}\right){\rm d}y
$$
Help me to solve the equation.

The solution will be appreciated in the hypergeometric function format.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help.
as u can see someone already downvoted the post.

Needs more information.  For example, report what happened when you attempted this at Wolfram Alpha.

Tyma Gaidash the y is multiplied in the denominator

Mathematica gives: $\int_0^x y^{\alpha -1} , _2F_1\left(a+b,a;a+1;\frac{a t}{(b-1) y}\right) , dy=\frac{a^{1+\alpha } (1-b)^{-\alpha } t^{\alpha } \Gamma (-\alpha ) \Gamma (a+b+\alpha )}{(a+\alpha ) \Gamma (a+b)}+\frac{(1-b)^{-\alpha } (x-b x)^{\alpha } , _2F_1\left(a,a+b;1+a;\frac{a t}{(-1+b)
x}\right)}{a+\alpha }+\frac{a (1-b)^{-\alpha } (x-b x)^{\alpha } , _2F_1\left(a+b,-\alpha ;1-\alpha ;\frac{a t}{(-1+b) x}\right)}{\alpha  (a+\alpha )}$

That “suitable formula” is unreadable.

Substitute $\frac1y\to y$ and then you can apply the formula in the question

Approach Zero website, link : https://approach0.xyz/search/

@NaveraKarim What, if anything, can we assume about the parameters? Are $a,b,x,t,\alpha$ all positive? Is $b<1$?
